# Angularjs aside to change $scope param

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My idea is to make templates (for questions) selectable in an aside element.

For creating an aside element in angularjs i tried around with [dbtek/angular-aside](https://github.com/dbtek/angular-aside). This works pretty nice, but my problem is that i have to store the template in an extra template file and i need to change an existing $scope variable (to set the template in the form).

Example:

**create_question.html** (button to open aside element & display template variable)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="openAside('left')">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> Right
</button>

Choosen template is {{choosenTemplate}}
```

**create_question.js** (var for choosen template, function to open aside element & function to change template var)

```
$scope.choosenTemplate = 0;  // 0 = default

$scope.openAside = function(position) {
  $aside.open({
    templateUrl: 'aside.html'
    placement: position,
    backdrop: true,
    controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
      $scope.ok = function(e) {
        $modalInstance.close();
        e.stopPropagation();
      };
      $scope.cancel = function(e) {                  
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
        e.stopPropagation();
      };
    }
  })
};

$scope.setTemplate = function(templateNumber)
{
  $scope.choosenTemplate = templateNumber;
}
```

**aside.html** (template for aside element - content irrelevant)

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="setTemplate(2)">Template 2</button>   
</div>
```

The aside element is shown but the function is never called when i press the button.

When i change to

**aside.html**

```
<div ng-controller="CreateQuestionCtrl">
  <button ng-click="setTemplate(2)">Template 2</button>   
</div>
```

the function is called but now i have two different $scopes (i think)? And i can only change the wrong $scope Element (inside the aside).

Another try was to **set the template in a `<script>`-element** like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="aside.html">
  <button ng-click="setTemplate(2)">Template 2</button> 
</script>
```

and set this element inside the **create_question.html**, but now i can't call the function again.

Does anyone has an idea how i can have the same $scope on "two different" pages? Both are on the same page but i can't really access the same $scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably better ways to communicate between main and aside controllers, but it may work out as is.

`$aside` is just a wrapper around ui-bootstrap `$modal`. The example above doesn't make use of [`scope` parameter](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal):

> `scope` - a scope instance to be used for the modal's content (actually
>   the $modal service is going to create a child scope of a provided
>   scope). Defaults to $rootScope

It is essential for setting up the relationship between modal and parent controller scopes.

Doing

```
  $aside.open({
    scope: $scope,
    ...
```

should make the app work as expected.